# Conditional citation agreeing to parametized criteria

Tags: citing, conditionals

How can I include a citation only if it meets a certain criteria? Consider the following example, with improvised commands:

```
\citationlevel{1}

\citeif{1, something}
\citeif{2, something}
```

The first command `citationlevel` would appear in the preamble, and define the citation level for the entire document. If the level is lower that than that, then the citation appears, otherwise it doesn't. In the previous example, only the first citation would appear. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And another solution that its syntax is more similar to the proposed question.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\citationlevel#1{\def\citelevel{#1}}
\def\citeif#1{\expandafter\citeiff#1\relax}
\def\citeiff#1,#2\relax{\ifnum\numexpr#1-1<\citelevel\relax\cite{#2}\fi}

\citationlevel{2}

\begin{document}

\citeif{1, something1}
\citeif{2, something2}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The citation is printed, if the given level is less equal the `citationlevel`.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\citationlevel}{1}

\newcommand{\citeif}[2]{
    \ifnum \numexpr#1-1 < \citationlevel
        \cite{#2}
    \fi
}

\begin{document}

\citeif{1}{abramowitz}
\citeif{2}{einstein}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{literature}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works great, but I've decided to go with @javadr's one! Thank you, still